# Why does $\left\lvert1-\frac{h}{T}\right\rvert<1\implies0<\frac{h}{T}<2$?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Can someone please show how they restricted $\frac{h}{T}$?

> $$\left\lvert1-\frac{h}{T}\right\rvert<1\implies0<\frac{h}{T}<2$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\lvert a\rvert< b$ iff $-b<a<b$

Comment: If you had to put $\left|1-\frac hT\right|<1$ into words, and not just say "the absolute value of $1-\frac ht$ is less than $1$", what would you say?

Comment: Who are "they" ? Why did "they" make this restriction ? What are $h$ & $T$ ? Context should be included in your Post !

Answer (score 0):

$$\left\lvert1-\frac{h}{T}\right\rvert<1\implies-1<1-\frac{h}{T}<1\implies-2<-\frac{h}{T}<0\implies0<\frac{h}{T}<2
$$